# text in tkinter Text window is close to scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, scrollbar, tkinter.optionmenu

I made a text editor with a scrollbar added.
I have two main issues here.

1. The problem I am facing is that my text does not completely go to the next line when it is
   close to the right side and the last character just hides under the scroll bar.  I want the
   word should either move to the next line or the character should not go behind the scroll bar.
2. I have an option of changing fonts but the fonts list is unsorted and it is difficult to find the specific font. I don't know how to make it sorted or better option how to add a search widget for selection of specific font just like in Microsoft word editor.

Here is my code :

```
import os.path
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser, font
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *

'''
This is a text editior which can open save make new files
The fonts and color of text is changeable.
'''

def change_color():
    color = colorchooser.askcolor(title="Pick any color")
    text_area.config(fg=color[1])


def change_font(*args):
    text_area.config(font=(font_name.get(), size_box.get()))


def new_file():
    window.title("Untitled")
    text_area.delete(1.0, END)


def open_file():
    # from filedialog module it gives just the file directry and opening GUI
    file_name = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt",
                                filetypes=[("Text Documents", '.txt'),
                                           ("All files",'*.*')])
    # if window is closed without selecting a file.
    # comparing it to none did not have effect as file is str type
    # and has empty string when nothing is selected
    if file_name == "":
        print("No file was selected")
        return

    try:
        window.title(os.path.basename(file_name))
        text_area.delete(1.0, END)
        # This builtin open function opens the file in given address
        file = open(file_name, 'r')
        # writes at start the strings text in file.read()
        text_area.insert(1.0, file.read())

    except Exception:
        print("File could not be opened")

    finally:
        file.close()

def save_file():
    file = asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt',
                                       defaultextension='.txt',
                                       filetypes=[('All files','.*'),
                                                 ('Text Documents','.txt')])

   # if window is closed without selecting a file.
   # comparing it to none did not have effect as file is str type
   # and has empty string when nothing is selected
    if file == "" :
        print("No file was selected")
        return
    try:
        window.title(os.path.basename(file))
        file = open(file, 'w')
        file.write(text_area.get(1.0, END))
    except Exception:
        print("Could not save file")
    finally:
            file.close()

def copy():
    text_area.event_generate("<<Copy>>") # dont know how this function works

def cut():
    text_area.event_generate("<<Cut>>") # dont know how this function works

def paste():
    text_area.event_generate("<<Paste>>") # dont know how this function works

def about():
    # Using message box modue
    howinfo("About this program","This is a text editor")

def close():
    window.destroy()

window = Tk()
window.title("Text Editor")
window_height = 500
window_width = 500

# Screen display size of my PC
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
print(screen_width)
print(screen_height)

# To make the window appear in centre.
x = int((screen_width / 2) - (window_width / 2))
y = int((screen_height / 2) - (window_height / 2))

window.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(window_width, window_height,x,y))

# default font selection
font_name  = StringVar(window)
font_name.set('Arial')

font_size = StringVar(window)
font_size.set("25")

# adding text area to write and attach scroll bar to it.
text_area = Text(window, font=(font_name.get(), font_size.get()))
scrollbar = Scrollbar(text_area)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# adding scroll bar to our text area
text_area.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

#This line is making text move by scroll.
scrollbar.config(command=text_area.yview, cursor='arrow')

# This will make text to span when window is expanded or compressed
window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
text_area.grid(sticky=N + E + S + W)

frame =Frame(window)
frame.grid()

# making color change , spin and font changing buttons
color_button = Button(frame, text="color", command=change_color)
color_button.grid(row=0,column=0)

# Option menu from font class
font_change = OptionMenu(frame, font_name, *font.families(),
                         command=change_font)
font_change.grid(row=0, column=1)

#spinbox for changing font size
size_box = Spinbox(frame, from_=1, to=100,  textvariable=font_size,
                   command=change_font)
size_box.grid(row=0, column=2)


#menu tabs
menu_bar = Menu(window)
window.config(menu=menu_bar)

# File menu
file_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="New File", command=new_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=save_file)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=close)


# Edit menu
edit_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit_menu)
edit_menu.add_command(label="copy", command=copy)
edit_menu.add_command(label="paste", command=paste)
edit_menu.add_command(label="cut", command=cut)
edit_menu.add_separator()

# help menu
help_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label='help', menu=help_menu)
help_menu.add_command(label='About', command=about)

window.mainloop()
```

**Problem picture:**

[image: scroll bar issue]

[image: fonts issue]

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time, and please make sure your code is minimal. For example, nothing in this question requires the menubar or most of the functions.

Comment: @BryanOakley sorry for posting my whole code. I am new to asking questions. I will follow the best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For issue 1, you need to put the scrollbar in `window` instead of `text_area`:

```py
text_area = Text(window, font=(font_name.get(), font_size.get()))
scrollbar = Scrollbar(window)
...
text_area.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+E+S+W)
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
```

For issue 2, you can sort the list using `sorted()`:

```py
font_change = OptionMenu(frame, font_name, *sorted(font.families()),
                         command=change_font)
```

Comment: i tried your solution for issue 1. but now the scroll function is not working. it does not scroll the text. if i add the following line now the scroll can be moved but it does not move the text pan. #This line is making text move by scroll.                                                                              
scrollbar.config(command=text_area.yview, cursor='arrow')                                                 However the sorted function worked i also tried before but i was using it wrong. thanks for the second solution.

Comment: My solution for issue 1 is just changing the parent of the scrollbar and does not affect the behaviour of the scrollbar.

Comment: I just tested your code with my changes, it works fine in my Python 3.10.2 environment.

Answer (score 0):

#TK

text_area0 = Text(window, font=(font_name.get(), font_size.get()))

scrollbar1 = Scrollbar(window)

text_area.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+E+S+W)

scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When answering questions you should try to explain what or why something is required, and what the issue with the original the original poster had was. 

You should try not to just provide some lines of code which may fix the issue, also as the question asker may not know where to place or modify these code lines.

You can also format code to make it easier to read.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).